# How do I terminate a SwingWorker?

Tags: java

I am trying to set up a swing worker that will terminate my block of code, but when I run it (hit the Cancel Button), I get the following errors (and the for loop just keeps plugging along, unlike I would expect):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
```

If I uncomment "TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);" in the for loop, then the for loop exits when I push the Cancel button, like I would expect.

NewClass.java

```
package examplesw;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

/**
 *
 * @author macdays
 */
public class NewClass {

    // Variables
    int temp1;
    SwingWorker sw1; 

    // Constructor
    public NewClass() {
        temp1 = 1;  
    }


    //methods

    public void runMyLoop() {
        sw1 = new SwingWorker(){          

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws IOException, CancellationException, InterruptedException {                              

                for (int i = 0; i < 123456; i++){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }

                /*
                System.out.println("Writing database...");
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\codiac\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NtbnsProjJoojle\\temp.txt");
                String myString;
                for (int i = 0; i < 2345678; i++){
                        myString = "line " + i;
                        writer.write(myString + System.lineSeparator());
                        //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(0);
                        //TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(1);
                }
                writer.close();
                System.out.println("...database written.");
               */

                String myString = "task completed";
                return myString;
            }

            @Override
            public void done() {                
                try {                
                    String msg = (String) get();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(exampleswJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(exampleswJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }    
        };
        sw1.execute();
    }      
}
```

examplesswJFrame.java

```
package examplesw;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

/**
 *
 * @author macdays
 */
public class exampleswJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // Variables belonging to examplesJFrame

    public NewClass nw_cls;

    /**
     * Creates new form exampleswJFrame
     */
    public exampleswJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        runButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cancelButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        runButton.setText("Run");
        runButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                runButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        cancelButton.setText("Cancel");
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cancelButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(cancelButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(runButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(runButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(cancelButton)
                .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void cancelButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        nw_cls.sw1.cancel(true);
    }                                            

    private void runButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       nw_cls = new NewClass();
       nw_cls.runMyLoop();
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(exampleswJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(exampleswJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(exampleswJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(exampleswJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new exampleswJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton cancelButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton runButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

@matt I corrected the nw_cls = new NewClass(). It just kept creating new references, you're right. Thank you. I will post my updated code once I clean it all up. I have a really nice solution.

Comment: The right way to terminate a swing worker is to wait for it to complete.

Comment: More here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/cancel.html  This is all *if you must.*  Normally you don't want to do this.

Comment: Echoing the previous comments: your worker should terminate on its own because it's done running what needed to run. So: can you explain _why_ you're trying to terminate it manually? Because it sounds like you may have misunderstood how to use them and are trying to solve a problem that only exists as a symptom of using the wrong approach.

Comment: When you do `.cancel(true);` you're allowing the SW to be interrupted. When you have Thread.sleep, it gets interrupted and your loop ends. You should add a check to `isCancelled()` and break your loop if it is cancelled.

Comment: Pomax: I am trying to terminate it in case the user initiated a process that will take forever to complete. I don't want to waste resources if I don't have to. What if the user clicked the "Run" button a bunch of times? Wouldn't that eventually bog down the application and the computer it's running on?

Comment: markspace: The code I wrote is based on the concurrency link you provided.

Comment: matt: I will give isCancelled() a try. This should suit my needs. I'm just worried I'm being sloppy based on the other comments.

Comment: @macdays if you include the '@' it will notify people of your response. There are a few cases they'll automatically be notified.

Comment: In regards to using 'isCancelled` being sloppy, it is one way to have the task complete. Have it check to see if it should continue running or stop. *If* your task would not finish in a reasonable amount of time anyways. Maybe you have a continuously running task, that would never complete, but you want to be able to stop it. In that case you might want a different abstraction than a SwingWorker. In regards to a user clicking run a bunch of times, your design is very broken. `nw_cls = new NewClass();` loses a reference to your old one, and starts a new one.

Comment: @matt I don't see how to use something other than a swing worker. I want a progress bar to show when the user clicks Run (jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(true)). I tried using a thread with a runnable interface, but didn't know how to turn off the progress bar once the thread completed. Swing worker handles this because it has a listener for when the worker completes. Then I can turn off the progress bar with "jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(false)."

Comment: You've missed the point of my comment a bit. Using 'isCancelled' is fine. It's hard to talk in the abstract. "Turning off the progress bar..." seems pretty trivial regardless of a thread or SwingWorker. The main point: if you want a Thread/SwingWorker to stop, ask it to stop, and then the executing logic should stop (check isCancelled or interrupted ) or if the task is short, just ignore the cancel and finish normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'isCancelled' is fine. It's hard to talk in the abstract. "Turning off the progress bar..." seems pretty trivial regardless of a thread or SwingWorker. The main point: if you want a Thread/SwingWorker to stop, ask it to stop, and then the executing logic should stop (check isCancelled or interrupted ) or if the task is short, just ignore the cancel and finish normally.